# Xcode: Convert "Command Line Tool" Project to "C/C++ Library" Project

Tags: xcode, xcode4

If I have a "Command Line Tool" project in Xcode, and just want to build a "C/C++ Library", can I convert my existing project without deleting the project file and starting from scratch? (I want to maintain all my groups / organization / settings / etc).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone wondering the same thing I was, here's the solution:

My first problem was forgetting/not realizing that "projects" and "targets" are two different things in Xcode. In the Microsoft world, "projects" have "type"s (Class Library / Application / etc). Not so in Xcode.

So, if you want to build a Static Library, the solution is simple; just add a "Static Library" target:

[image: Adding a new target]